# use an array variable in twig

Tags: twig, symfony4

I got a variable from a controller in the form of an array (variable ads), on twig, I used:

```
{% for ad in ads%}
<tr> <td> {{ad.xxx}}
 {% if app.user and app.user == ad.author%}
{{ad.yyyy}}
{% endif%}
</td> </tr>
{$ endfor%}
```

there is no problem, it's classic.
 I want to use for example

```
{% if app.user and app.user == ad.author%}
```

just before the for loop, to hide a balise for logged in users but it’s not their announcement

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? The code you've provided should work as is. See [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ahxcth)

Comment: look the code  https://twigfiddle.com/khjw1c

Comment: Yes.. and what is the problem? You're just testing if there is an user and the post has an author on #10. In your code here you are doing the equation

Comment: I want to do that : {% if app.user %}

                                        {% for ad in userAds %}
                                        {% if app.user == ad.author %}
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}

                                    {% endif %} but I have 5 times the <th> action </th>             if there is a connected user and if the advertisement belongs to the connected user

Comment: Sorry I think everyone is really confused as to a) what the problem is b) What would fix it.

Comment: [link]twigfiddle.com/khjw1c [link]     on line 10 we don't have the ad variable, we just have a userAds array !! I cannot use the for loop because the <th> </th> tag will be repeated as many times as the iterations of the loop, in the for loop I have the variable I want: ad.author, my queqtion: is how to get this variable outside of the for loop.
if leave my code as it is, I have the error it does not know the ad variable !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `userAds` is a collection from ads from one and the same author, you could go with the following snippet(s):

```html
{{ attribute(userAds|first, 'author') }}

{{ (userAds|first).author}}

{{ (userAds|first)['author'] }}
```

---

```html
{% if app.user and (userAds|first).author == app.user %}
    <th>Action</th>
{% endif %}
```